# Controlling which classes GWT includes with -generateJsInteropExports

Tags: gwt, gwt-jsinterop

Can I control which classes are included when I use `-generateJsInteropExports`?

I'm finding that when I use the flag, the JS output includes a bunch of classes that I'm not using in the project, but whose source appears in some of the packages I'm using. I don't want these classes to be included in the output. Normally, GWT does a good job of only bringing in classes that I'm actually using.

How can I tell the compiler "in this compilation I'd like you to generate JsInterop for these classes, but not these"?

I found these [GWT compiler options](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions):

```
-includeJsInteropExports/excludeJsInteropExports
```

> Include/exclude members and classes while generating JsInterop exports. Flag could be set multiple times to expand the pattern. (The flag has only effect if exporting is enabled via -generateJsInteropExports)

But I couldn't seem to get them to work. I tried using:

```
-generateJsInteropExports
-includeJsInteropExports com.example.MyClass
```

The class wasn't included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering is at the level of class member (i.e. fields and methods) rather than type name. To match all members of a class the syntax is:

```
-generateJsInteropExports
-includeJsInteropExports com.example.MyClass.*
```

Note: It's a regular expression, so the dots represent "any character" rather than periods. You'd have to escape them if there were ambiguity.